# Running Application Automatiacally

Tags: linux, embedded, powerpc

I am using MPC8323E-RDB development board for Embedded-Linux development for applications. Here, I want to run my application automatically upon boot-up. I tested by changing `/etc/inittab` file, but application is not running automatically. I tried to run Hello_world C program which is cross-compiled for my target.

How can I run this application automatically upon boot-up?

Comment: Mr Reddy Signature is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, check you can run your app interactively (e.g. from a shell). That will rule out issue with cross-compilation, which can go wrong quite easily.

Once you verify that it works, you could try running it from `/etc/rc.local`. On most distros, this should run automatically on startup.

There's also lots of help on the internet about when rc.local fails to start on boot. I don't know what distro your board runs, but [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9853/how-can-i-make-rc-local-run-on-startup) about Ubuntu has good advice.